# How to modify the configuration file name when spring boot Maven is packaged, such as config. xml. re to config. XML

Tags: maven

我在兼容老项目时必须用到个config的配置文件
我该怎么用spring boot Maven 打包时如何修改配置文件名称，比如把config.xml.re修改成config.xml

已经解决

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <move file="${project.build.directory}/classes/config-${profileActive}.xml"
                                      tofile="${project.build.directory}/classes/config.xml"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: plz speak english(請使用英文)

Comment: It is nothing to do with Spring Boot, you can achieve it by using Maven plugin.

Comment: I think I've solved it.

Comment: are you solved it?